# What reasons might a POST request need to be made without a form?

Tags: http, post

I would like to know why a developer would make a POST request without using a form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `GET` and `POST` do not have the same semantic value. `GET` requests should be generally safe to perform at any time without compromising the system, while `POST` requests should be used when doing something important (like accepting a monetary transaction, or, in a less dramatic way, post a comment or something like that).

So it might make sense to make a `POST` request through AJAX if its result will affect a system.

**Source**: [W3C HTTP/1.1 Method Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), read **9.1.1 Safe Methods**, **9.3 GET** and **9.5 POST**. Don't be afraid, it's short and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

To test the form for one. Then ajax requests can use post data. Also in php at leats you have curl wich I am pretty sure can make use of the post structure to communicate other distant pages.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to call a REST API, or other web services that require POST, or to upload a file to a server. You could use AJAX/JavaScript on client side, and just about any server side technology to mimic POST without a form.

Answer (score 1):

`POST` is an HTTP verb. Browsers use HTTP as its data protocol for fetching HTML data and `POST` for sending the user submitted data. Basically, any data transfer over http could use POST.

Some of the examples are :

- [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)
- [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)
  etc...